# How can I protect my Apps Script code / hide database login details?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to pull data into a Google doc from a MySQL database (quote / invoice data) via a Google Apps Script. The doc will be used by several people (in a small agency). However these project managers should not be able to see the login details that are embedded in the Apps Script Code. I don't care if they see the Code. So is there a trick to hide or lock the login details for the database? Any advice??

Comment: Don't embed it. Put it in propertiesService/run with installable trigger and/or create a private add-on or use a standalone script.

Comment: @TheMaster ... just curious, why not a contained web app and what’s the trigger for.

Comment: Properties Service / Script Properties are not really hidden from a user with edit access to the spreadsheet.  If the user has edit permissions to the Sheet, then they have edit permissions to the Apps Script project file, and if they have edit permissions to the Apps Script project file, then they can navigate to "File" "Project properties" - and the Script Properties tab.  Please don't think that doing it that way will be in anyway secure.  It's better to create a private or unlisted add-on.  Or you could have a stand alone apps script file in-between your Sheet code and your database.

Comment: @Cooper container web-app source can still be accessed by editors of spreadsheet, I believe. The trigger - If the script is set to run say , onEdit() , Installable triggers runs under the authority of the one, who installed the trigger(say, owner), not as the user at the keyboard. The implication being, such script can access userProperties of the owner.

Comment: @Sandy As riyafa answered, I think userProperties can only be accessed by the user that created those properties. And I believe File > project properties will only show scriptProperties and/or current user's properties. If OP doesn't need access to db from other users execution of script, I think it's safer. Correct me, If I'm wrong.

Comment: The users are using a Google Doc, so my assumption is, that the script is bound to the Doc.  And I think that the script is running under the authority of the user, not the owner.  So, an editor of the Doc should not be able to access User Property settings of the owner.  And if the user can't access User Properties of the owner of the Doc/Script, then the code can't get the setting.  And there's no point in putting the setting into every individual users properties.  Because they could access the settings, plus it would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 3):

Google apps script has a concept called [properties services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties). You can use the Script properties or the user properties to stored your credentials:

**Script properties** are shared among all users of a script, add-on, or web app. They are typically used for app-wide configuration data, like the username and password for the developer's external database.

Usage:

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
//setting
scriptProperties.setProperty('SERVER_URL', 'http://www.example.com/');
//retrieving
var units = userProperties.getProperty('DISPLAY_UNITS');
```

**User properties** are shared among the current user of a script, add-on, or web app and typically used for User-specific settings, like metric or imperial units.

Usage:

```
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
//setting
userProperties.setProperty('DISPLAY_UNITS', 'metric');
//retrieving
var units = userProperties.getProperty('DISPLAY_UNITS');
```

You can also manually set, view or remove these properties by going to `File->Properties` and the relevant tab.

There is also the third kind of property called document properties about which you can find out [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties).

Comment: It would seem someone smart enough could simply include a script to expose the properties?

Comment: He can expose properties that only he has access to

Answer (score 2):

As some of you mentioned, the problem is that a user could read out the login details stored externally with an appropriate script. So my solution for now is to run the SQL select in a standalone script embedded as web app and to let the standalone script write the query result into a spreadsheet. The editable doc will then Import the data from there.